# cvInvert() of matrix returns 0 matrix? but return actual values in Matlab

Tags: opencv

here is the origial matrix that I want to invert:

```
rows: 5
   cols: 5
   dt: f
   data: [ 927321., 1014163., 923303., 923303., 947641., 1014163.,
       1260101., 1062130., 1062130., 1102823., 923303., 1062130.,
       1004488., 1004488., 990651., 923303., 1062130., 1004488.,
       1004488., 990651., 947641., 1102823., 990651., 990651., 1116004. ]
```

and using this line to invert the above matrix:

```
cvInvert(Mult, Inv, CV_LU);
```

The matrix returned after inverse is this:

```
rows: 5
   cols: 5
   dt: f
   data: [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. ]
```

and according to documentation:

> In the case of LU method, the function returns the src1 determinant
>   (src1 must be square). If it is 0, the matrix is not inverted and src2
>   is filled with zeros.

But the strange thing is that I asked my friend to do the same in Matlab using this same matrix and it returned a non-zero matrix.. that means that the determinant is not zero.. then why does opencv think the determinant is zero?

Thanks

Comment: Any chance of overflow?  Those numbers are somewhat large, but I am not familiar with the memory size of float/double/numbers on Opencv to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The given matrix is rank deficient (determinant is zero) and therefore you cannot compute its inverse.

Answer (score 0):

According to an online matrix inverter, the inverse is:

`0.000            0.000            0.000            0.000            0.000

0.000            0.000            0.000            0.000            0.000

0.000            0.000  68719476736.000 -68719476736.000            0.000

0.000            0.000 -68719476736.000  68719476736.000            0.000

0.000            0.000            0.000            0.000            0.000`

That is a very strange looking matrix and the remaining terms are very, very huge.  This means the online calculator has issues because the determiniate is so so big, your routine overflows on the determinate because of the size, or both.  I'd be willing to bet that MatLab won't have these type of size restrictions, hence the valid value from it.

Comment: what is I normalize the values? that should fix the overflow? anyway to normalize values in opencv?

Comment: Normalization will change your inverse.  I am wondering what or how this very large 5x5 matrix is obtained and perhaps if the values coming in could be shrunk?

Comment: this matrix is obtained by multiplying a matrix by its transpose.. I have updated the above question with the matrix and the line I am using to multiply them. I am guesing that my multiplicatin is somehow wrong..